# ERROR 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, laravel

How can I solved this one I've been try all the possible solution but nothing happened. Just the same error shown

ERROR 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)

this is the code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAttributeValueProductAttributeTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('attribute_value_product_attribute', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('attribute_value_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('attribute_value_id')->references('id')->on('attribute_values');
            $table->bigInteger('product_attribute_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_attribute_id')->references('id')->on('product_attributes');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('attribute_value_product_attribute');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full error please

Answer (score 0):

```
    $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('attribute_value_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('attribute_value_id')->references('id')->on('attribute_values');
        $table->integer('product_attribute_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_attribute_id')->references('id')->on('product_attributes');$table->timestamps();
```

please copy paste this as it is and let me know that it works for you or not, if not than please let me the exact error. thank you